# How to take a double limit keeping a certain ratio fixed?

Tags: limits

How to take the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$ and $q \rightarrow \infty$ of the expression $\binom{N}{q}$ such that $\frac{q^{2}}{N}= \lambda$.  Can I substitute $N = \frac{q^2}{\lambda}$ and then take $q \rightarrow \infty$ in the resulting equation? Is this a valid step to do?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.

Comment: @ConnorGordon Thank you so much, I just needed this much only. I will carry out everything else on my own now.